# Better coding of making a check each time function runs

Tags: javascript, variables

I am trying to eliminate the useless check in a function, needed check variable is assigned at start-up of the app, so I don't want to check for it each time.

I have a code like this:

```
btnClose.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    window.close()
    if (appSettings.sendAnonymousStats) {
      visitor.event("Application", "App has been closed.").send()
    }
})
```

This is my first try to optimize it, so now it doesn't need to do a "if" check each time it's called;

```
let btnCloseEv = appSettings.sendAnonymousStats ? btnClose.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    window.close()
    visitor.event("Application", "App has been closed.").send()
    }) : btnClose.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    window.close()
})
```

I wonder  if theoretically there are better ways to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating this. The use of the `click` event is exactly what its for, the `if` is warranted in there and it makes your code easily parseable. And since it's only triggered on `click`, its execution isn't ongoing in the background hogging resources. Seems perfectly fine.

Comment: I know but I was actually asking theoretically if there's a better approach.

Comment: Agreed, just check the variable. There is no problem with that....

Comment: why not re-asisgn other function to click event after click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing a single if statement, especially considering it only occurs once per click will not effect running time at all.

However for the purpose of discussion say it was performance critical, like if it was attached to onmousemove, then you can adjust your second approach with a small change to reduce code redundancy.

```
let btnCloseEv = btnClose.addEventListener('click',
    appSettings.sendAnonymousStats ?
    function(e) {
        window.close();
        visitor.event("Application", "App has been closed.").send();
    } : function(e) {
        window.close();
    }
)
```

This works because functions in JS are higher order functions, which means they treated as variables and can be passed around in the same way variables can be. For instance this would work if a and b were numbers, or functions, or any other type of variable.

```
var c = someBoolean ? a : b;
```

---

Say each function was a lot bigger and you wanted to use this approach yet things were becoming unreadable, it would be better to name each function and attach them like so:

```
function moreComplexFunc(e) {
    window.close();
    visitor.event("Application", "App has been closed.").send();
    // More complex code
}

function simpleFunc(e) {
    window.close();
}

let btnCloseEv = btnClose.addEventListener(
    'click',
    appSettings.sendAnonymousStats ? moreComplexFunc : simpleFunc
)
```

---

Now say that you noticed there was a lot of code duplication in `moreComplexFunc` and `simpleFunc`, you could go a step further, and separate the similar code into a 3rd function like so:

```
function commonFunc(e) {

    window.close();
}

function func1(e) {
    commonFunc(e);

    visitor.event("Application", "App has been closed.").send();

    // other code
}

function func2(e) {
    commonFunc(e);

    // other code
}

let btnCloseEv = btnClose.addEventListener(
    'click',
    appSettings.sendAnonymousStats ? func1 : func2
)
```

The opportunities in a language which supports Higher Order Functions are really endless.

Comment: If the function was a little more complex though, this approach would dramatically decrease readability for a minimal performance advantage. Just saying. Still, if the function is small and the check performance critical, this is the best way to go.

Comment: Yep @marsze I totally agree, I would not do this in practice unless I had found a bottleneck through testing, which for something this trivial would never be an issue. However if the code was more complex I would probably name each function and write (this is sudo code) addListener(bool ? myFunc1 : myFunc2); so everything was separated and more readable.

Comment: @marsze I have updated my original answer for you :) It now includes an example of how to increase readability.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case the function was a little more complex, another approach would be to simply put it in an additional event handler:

```
let btnCloseEv = btnClose.addEventListener('click',
    function(e) {
        window.close();
        /*
        ... more code ...
        */
    }
)

if (appSettings.sendAnonymousStats) {
    btnClose.addEventListener('click',
        function(e) {
             visitor.event("Application", "App has been closed.").send();
        }
}
```